# Section suppression formulas for multi-select parameters in Crystal Reports 11.5

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I'm trying to figure out how to create a section suppression formula that evaluates all the selections in a multi-select parameter. For instance, if the parameter is "Program" and you can select from IIH, PSYCH, TCM, THER, or PRTF then I would like to have a formula that does the following:

If "IIH" is the only program selected then suppress
If "IIH" and "THER" are selected then suppress
If any other combination then don't suppress.

The issue i'm having is that I can't find out how Crystal stores the values in that parameter. It seems that it only accounts for the first entry when using {?Program} in the formula.

Is this something simple i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula I used. I got a subscript error when evaluating parameters, so I had to go directly to the database fields.

My example is from Employees Table with Job Title field. This translates to your Program and Psychology Departments.

`If {Employees.Job Title} = ["Sales Manager","Sales Coordinator"]
and UBound({?title}) = 2 
Then True`

It seems Crystal checks arrays like an IN statement in SQL. I had to add a second check to make sure there are only two values in the array.

[Proof of my work](https://github.com/sunk818/crystal/tree/master/SuppressIfTwoMatchesInArray)